# Get free port for WebApi OWIN self host when running tests in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, owin, ncrunch

I'm using OWIN to Self-Host Web API while running my tests in **parallel** using NCrunch and I'm starting it in BeforeEach and stoping in AfterEach methods.

Before each test I'm trying to get available free port, but usually 5-10 tests out of 85 fails with the following exception:

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException : Failed to listen on prefix  
'http://localhost:3369/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
```

So it appears, that sometimes I do not get available port. I tried to use [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class in order to share last used port between multiple threads, but it didn't help.

Here's my tests base class:

```
public class BaseSteps
{
    private const int PortRangeStart = 3368;
    private const int PortRangeEnd = 8968;
    private static long _portNumber = PortRangeStart;
    private IDisposable _webServer;

    //.....

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void Before()
    {
        Url = GetFullUrl();
        _webServer = WebApp.Start<TestStartup>(Url);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void After()
    {
        _webServer.Dispose();
    }

    private static string GetFullUrl()
    {
        var ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;

        var portAvailable = GetAvailablePort(PortRangeStart, PortRangeEnd, ipAddress);

        return String.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", "localhost", portAvailable);
    }

    private static int GetAvailablePort(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd, IPAddress ip, bool includeIdlePorts = false)
    {
        IPGlobalProperties ipProps = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

        // if the ip we want a port on is an 'any' or loopback port we need to exclude all ports that are active on any IP
        Func<IPAddress, bool> isIpAnyOrLoopBack = i => IPAddress.Any.Equals(i) ||
                                                       IPAddress.IPv6Any.Equals(i) ||
                                                       IPAddress.Loopback.Equals(i) ||
                                                       IPAddress.IPv6Loopback.
                                                           Equals(i);
        // get all active ports on specified IP.
        List<ushort> excludedPorts = new List<ushort>();

        // if a port is open on an 'any' or 'loopback' interface then include it in the excludedPorts
        excludedPorts.AddRange(from n in ipProps.GetActiveTcpConnections()
                               where
                                   n.LocalEndPoint.Port >= rangeStart &&
                                   n.LocalEndPoint.Port <= rangeEnd && (
                                   isIpAnyOrLoopBack(ip) || n.LocalEndPoint.Address.Equals(ip) ||
                                    isIpAnyOrLoopBack(n.LocalEndPoint.Address)) &&
                                    (!includeIdlePorts || n.State != TcpState.TimeWait)
                               select (ushort)n.LocalEndPoint.Port);

        excludedPorts.AddRange(from n in ipProps.GetActiveTcpListeners()
                               where n.Port >= rangeStart && n.Port <= rangeEnd && (
                               isIpAnyOrLoopBack(ip) || n.Address.Equals(ip) || isIpAnyOrLoopBack(n.Address))
                               select (ushort)n.Port);

        excludedPorts.AddRange(from n in ipProps.GetActiveUdpListeners()
                               where n.Port >= rangeStart && n.Port <= rangeEnd && (
                               isIpAnyOrLoopBack(ip) || n.Address.Equals(ip) || isIpAnyOrLoopBack(n.Address))
                               select (ushort)n.Port);

        excludedPorts.Sort();

        for (int port = rangeStart; port <= rangeEnd; port++)
        {
            if (!excludedPorts.Contains((ushort)port) && Interlocked.Read(ref _portNumber) < port)
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _portNumber);

                return port;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make sure, that I **always** get available port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is here:

```
if (!excludedPorts.Contains((ushort)port) && Interlocked.Read(ref _portNumber) < port)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _portNumber);
    return port;
}
```

First of all, you can compute the `excludedPorts` once per test start, and store them in some static field.

Second, the issue is caused by wrong logic to define is port available or not: between `Interlocked.Read` and `Interlocked.Increment` other thread can do the same check and return the same port! EG:

1. Thread A: check for the `3369`: it isn't in `excludedPorts`, and `_portNumber` is equal to 3368, so check is passed. But stop, I'll think a while...
2. Thread B: check for the `3369`: it isn't in `excludedPorts`, and `_portNumber` is equal to 3368, so check is passed too! Wow, I'm so excited, let's `Increment` it, and return `3369`.
3. Thread A: OK, so where were we? Oh, yes, `Increment`, **and return `3369`!**

Typical race condition. You can resolve it with two ways:

- Use [CAS-operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) [`CompareExchange` from `Interlocked` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx) (and you can remove `port` variable, something like this (test this code by yourself, please):

  ```
  var portNumber = _portNumber;
  if (excludedPorts.Contains((ushort)portNumber))
  {
      // if port already taken
      continue;
  }
  if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _portNumber, portNumber + 1, portNumber) != portNumber))
  {
      // if exchange operation failed, other thread passed through
      continue;
  }
  // only one thread can succeed
  return portNumber;
  ```
- Use a static [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) of the ports, and add new ports to them, something like this (you may choose another collection):

  ```
  // static field in your class
  // value item isn't useful
  static ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool>() ports = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool>();

  foreach (var p in excludedPorts)
      // you may check here is the adding the port succeed
      ports.TryAdd(p, true);
  var portNumber = _portNumber;
  if (!ports.TryAdd(portNumber, true))
  {
      continue;
  }
  return portNumber;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I didn't get why in Interlocked.CompareExchange you're comparing 1st parameter to incremented 3rd parameter? Shoudn't you compare 1st to 3rd parameter and increase 2nd? I pasted some code with comments here: http://cspad.com/w4rb Could you please take a look and correct me where I'm wrong, because tests still fails and I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Tests fails cause of two different tests get the same port number. Yes, this was a typo

Comment: Try to run this code in `parallel.for` and see the results. Also your `_portNumber` should be `volatile`, and no< you can't simply use `++` operator as it isn't thread safe

Comment: Had to refactor my specflow tests a little bit, but finally made them work. Took your second approach with ConcurrentDictionary. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, I think that this is the best option. Good luck with your projects!

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question, but if it's for testing, look at the Microsoft.Owin.Testing nuget package. Instead of starting a self hosted service (with network layer overload), you can use an in-memory TestServer instance. Refactoring is easy: just use TestServer.Create<TestStartup> instead of WebApp.Start<TestStartup> and use the HttpClient property of the created instance.